# asp.net regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, richtext

I created a asp.net page. The rich text area and regular expression validator are existed in this page. I want to check the html span tag that is contained or not in the rich text area. And then, I don't know how to write expression in regular expression validator. Please, help me.

Comment: You need to add more detail and show your code. Do you not know how to use the Regexvalidator or are you struggling with the regex expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out if there's a `span` tag with *C#* in *ASP.NET* with the following regex:

```
bool existsSpan = Regex.IsMatch(areaText, "<span[^>]*>");
```

It searches for `<span` then none or some chars that is not `>`, and finally a `>`.